# Can i add object to another object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a object:

```
{'name1': 123, 'name2': 1111, 'name3': 2222}
```

How can I make an object of objects like:

```
{{'name1': 123},{'name2': 1111}, {'name3': 2222}}
```

i need that for bar graph JSON format

Comment: That makes no sense. Maybe it'd be best to explain what you're trying to do. And we can suggest possible data structures

Comment: im trying to make JSON data for c3 bar chart ..it requires {{},{},{}} format

Comment: that is not valid JSON. You're misunderstanding something

Answer (score 0):

The structure you want is invalid, instead you can create an array of objects `[{'name1': 123},{'name2': 1111}, {'name3': 2222}]`

```
var obj = {
    'name1': 123,
    'name2': 1111,
    'name3': 2222
};
var array = [],
    tmp;
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        tmp = {};
        tmp[key] = obj[key];
        array.push(tmp)
    }
}
console.log(array)
```